# Python code simple Calculator with Tkinter i'am noob in python. Is it posible?

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("skaiciuotuvas")
e = tk.Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=15)
e.insert(0, 0)
```

## Button action functions

```
def button_click(number):

e.delete(0, "end")
current = e.get()
e.delete(0, "end")
e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))



def button_clear():

    e.delete(0, "end")
```

## this is simple calculiator that do num + num = res : need to get num + num + num ...etc = rez is it posible corecct this code

```
def button_add():

    first_number = int(e.get()) 
    global f_num
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, "end")
```

## is it posible to do only with def button_add(): function?

```
def button_equal():

    second_number = e.get() 
    e.delete(0, "end") 
    e.insert(0, int(second_number)+ f_num)
```

buttons this is spec num values for my projet

```
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(-30))

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(-20))
button3 = tk.Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(-18))
button4 = tk.Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(-16))
button5 = tk.Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(-15))
button6 = tk.Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(-12))
button7 = tk.Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(-7))
button8 = tk.Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button9 = tk.Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button10 = tk.Button(root, text="10", padx=37, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(10))
button_15 = tk.Button(root, text="-15", padx=34, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(-15))
button_add = tk.Button(root, text="+", padx=39, pady=20, command= button_add)
button_equal = tk.Button(root, text="=", padx=86, pady=20, command= button_equal)
button_clear = tk.Button(root, text="C", padx=39, pady=20, command=button_clear)
```

#put buttons on screen

```
button2.grid(row=3, column=2)
button3.grid(row=3, column=1)
button4.grid(row=3, column=0)

button5.grid(row=2, column=2)
button6.grid(row=2, column=1)
button7.grid(row=2, column=0)

button8.grid(row=1, column=2)
button9.grid(row=1, column=1)
button10.grid(row=1, column=0)

button_add.grid(row=4, column=2)
button_15.grid(row=5, column=0)
button1.grid(row=4, column=1)

button_equal.grid(row=5,column=1, columnspan=2)
button_clear.grid(row=4,column=0)




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "is it possible" is not a  good question to ask, since the answer quite often is simply "yes". What you're asking is indeed possible. I recommend you write a new [mcve] that focuses on just a couple of buttons. Try to solve the simplest possible case, and then add more buttons later. There are _many_ examples of tkinter based calculators on this site. Seek them out to see how they solve a similar problem to yours.

Comment: Thank's sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The problem isn't with your english, it's with the giant wall of code for a relatively simple question.

Comment: Yes it's 100% possible @darude